# How do I detect a reinstall of the app and delete the files I've created on the device's memory beforehand

Tags: android

In my app I create some files and I store them on internal storage/sd card. I want to detect reinstall and detele them when a reinstall occurs or better yet, make them in a way that will make them automatically deleted when app is uninstalled. is this possible?

EDIT:

```
directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

- this is where I store my files and they do not get deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most Android devices, files put on `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getDatabaseDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, and `getExternalCacheDir()` will be automatically removed when the app is uninstalled. Support for automatic deletion for the two external ones did not kick until until API Level 9 or so, IIRC.

Comment: I put my files on directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), and they do not get deleted :(

Comment: I do not necessarily need to store them there, its just that this is the only way I know. what do you suggest I change that line to?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: "and they do not get deleted" -- that's not one of the ones that I listed. "what do you suggest I change that line to?" -- `getExternalFilesDir()`. That is a method on `Context` and so is available on any `Activity` or `Service`.